# Sockets not sending data

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently working on an instant messaging system that require a server and a client to communicate between each other.
I tried it in C++ using the default socket API.
The problem is that even if both programs (server & client) compile fine, there isn't any socket sent from the client that reaches the server.

I don't know what did I do wrong here (I went over my code like 5 times and even did it again from scratch, no success).
I used "debugs" messages to locate the problems and they all concern the processing loops that I use.

```cpp
// code from the server

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("fr-FR"));

    WSAData wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing winsock";
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); 
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing the socket ";
        return -2;
    }

    const unsigned short port = 9999;
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port); 
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 

    int res = bind(server, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (res != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error when binding";
        return -3;
    }

    res = listen(server, SOMAXCONN);
    if (res != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error on calling listen";
        return -4;
    }

    std::cout << "Server successfully launched" << std::endl;

    char buffer[1025];

    while (true)
    {
        sockaddr_in from = { 0 };
        int addrlen = sizeof(from);
        SOCKET newClient = accept(server, (SOCKADDR*)(&from), &addrlen);

        if (newClient != SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            std::cout << "Client connected successfully" << std::endl;

            int Bytes = recv(newClient, buffer, 1024, 0);

            if (Bytes <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            std::cout << "Message received from client : " << buffer << std::endl;
            send(newClient, buffer, 1024, 0); // send it back to client
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// code from the client 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

void sendMessage(SOCKET s);
void recvMessage(SOCKET s);

int main()
{
    std::locale::global(std::locale("fr-FR"));

    WSAData wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing winsock";
        return -1;
    }

    SOCKET server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Error initializing the socket ";
        return -2;
    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(9999);

    int res = bind(server, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (res != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error when binding";
        return -3;
    }

    if (connect(server, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Erreur when connecting : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -4;
    }

    std::cout << "You are connected to server" << std::endl;

    std::thread sending(sendMessage, server);
    std::thread receiving(recvMessage, server);

    sending.detach();
    receiving.detach();

    while (true)
    { }

    return 0;
}


void sendMessage(SOCKET s)
{
    while (true)
    {
        std::string buff;
        std::cout << "Type your message :" << std::endl;
        std::getline(std::cin, buff);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        int Bytes = send(s, buff.c_str(), 1024, 0);
        if (Bytes <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void recvMessage(SOCKET s)
{
    while (true)
    {
        char buffer[1025];
        int Bytes = recv(s, buffer, 1024, 0);
        if (Bytes <= 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "The server sent : " << buffer << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The server should display the message that a client has connected when the client is launched and displays the chat command, but the only thing displayed in the server console is the message saying that the server has launched correctly... Yet the client displays the message supposedly "received" by the server.

PS : I'm aware the code doesn't need that many "include" statements, it's just I didn't remember which ones contained which functions so I'd rather include more than not enough for anybody wanting to compile the code.

Comment: Unfortunately, because the shown code fails to meet all requirements of a [mcve], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to help you. Please visit the stackoverflow.com [help], with tips on [ask] good questions that are answerable.

Comment: Hi, I don't get why it doesn't meet all the requirements, what am I lacking ?

Comment: I am confused whether this is multiple source files or a single source file. Please divide up your code and clearly indicate which source file contains which source. I suggest that you first trying doing a simple client and server without threading. Doing so will help you to learn the basics of using sockets and the sockets API. 
Then learn about the `select()` function which allows you to wait until there is some activity on a socket such as data waiting to be read.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I divided up the code in two parts.
The problem doing so without threading would be that I couldn't both be waiting for a message from the server and sending one of my own, meaning that every time I send a message, I'd have to be waiting for the server to answer before sending another one.

By the way, I've read about the "select" method, it's just I don't know if it'll help my socket sending data basically.

Comment: @Soufiane to answer your question to Sam, look at the posted code; **only** the posted code. If we can copy/paste/compile/run that, and *only* that, and produce your issue, you have a genuine reproduction. If you can strip that reproduction down to *only* code required to produce the same problem, and we can *still* copy/paste/compile/run and reproduce the problem, *now* you have a [mcve]. Ex: My compiler pukes as soon as it sees `CLIENT`. I haven't a clue what that is. You do, but we're not mind readers, and we can't see your code. *Help us help you*.

Comment: My bad, sorry.
I'll add the constructor code in the op, thanks !

Comment: The constructor has nothing to do with anything. Which part of a description of a [mcve] you are unclear about? Can you take exactly what you have in your question, cut and paste it into new files, compile it ***by itself***, run it, and reproduce the problem you are asking about? Unless your answer is "yes", this is not a [mcve]. The shown code will obviously not compile. Therefore, it is not a [mcve].

Comment: Edited my code to match those criterias, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several Things:

First, this is wrong:

```
send(s, buff.c_str(), 1024, 0)
```

You're basically telling `send` that the buffer it addresses is a full 1kb, and to send it all. It hasn't a clue how much memory there is actually valid, and knows nothing about terminated strings.

Second, the client setup is wrong. Don't `bind` to a client socket; `connect` is sufficient. Notice these:

```
int res = bind(server, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if (res != 0)
{
    std::cout << "Error when binding";
    return -3;
}

if (connect(server, (const sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    std::cout << "Erreur when connecting : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
    return -4;
}
```

That bind shouldn't be there. The `connect` will bind to the socket if the connection can be made. Removing the bind section of the client, fixing the buffer management to be correct, and putting `closesocket` calls where they belong, and your program will be much further down the road to functional. There are still some question logic workflows, but  at least the connectivity will be setup better.

Comment: Removing the "bind" statement worked to link the client to the server, thanks.
But what about that whole kb thing, how to make it more efficient ?

Comment: @Soufiane That's not the posted question. If you want a code review you should take your updates to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.tackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks for the site, I'll give it a try if I finish the program with enough remaining time.